# Rails passing params in link_to how to make it secure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, parameters

I am trying to create a like and dislike function inside rails for that I am using lin_to helper to pass params but there is an issue when ever someone tries to copy paste the links it updated the database . I am using ajax to make this function work here is the code for my method .

Controller code:

```
class FeedLikesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! ,only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :get_feed ,only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    @fees = FeedLike.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
    end
  end

  def update
    @feed_likes = FeedLike.find_or_create_by(feed_like_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @feed_likes.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Like ' }
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @feed_like_counter = Feed.find(params[:feed_id])
    @feed_likes = FeedLike.find_or_create_by(:feed_id => params[:feed_id],:user_id =>params[:user_id])

    @f = @feed_like_counter.like_count
    @feed_like_counter.like_count = @f+1
    @feed_like_counter.save

    respond_to do |format|
      if @feed_likes.save 
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Like ' }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end


  def delete

  end

  def destroy
    @feed_like_counter = Feed.find(params[:feed_id])
    @feed_likes = FeedLike.where(feed_like_params)

    @f = @feed_like_counter.like_count
    @feed_like_counter.like_count = @f-1
    @feed_like_counter.save

    respond_to do |format|
      if @feed_likes.destroy_all
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Unlike ' }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def feed_like_params
    params.permit(:user_id, :feed_id)
    #params[:market_place]
  end

  def get_feed
    @feed = Feed.find(params[:feed_id])
  end

end
```

And in views my link is like this:

```
<div class="feed-like-<%= @feed %> " >
  <%= link_to "like",{ :action => 'create', :controller => 'feed_likes', :feed_id => @feed, :user_id => current_user.id, :remote => true }, method: :post,class: "btn btn-primary"   %>
</div>
```

And dislike link is like this:

```
<div class="feed-like-<%= @feed %> " >
  <%= link_to "Dislike",{ :action => 'destroy', :controller => 'feed_likes', :feed_id => @feed, :user_id => current_user.id, :remote => true }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>          
</div>
```

And my routes is like :

```
get "/feed_likes/:feed_id/feed_likes/:user_id" => "feed_likes#destroy"
post "/feed_likes/:feed_id/feed_likes/:user_id" => "feed_likes#create"
```

Here the issue is whenever someone wants to like the feed when I passes the url direclty it updated the database how can I restrict this only when user click the button only then it update the database not by url :

There is another issue with this I am using ajax onclick event it updated the database but when I click the like button fast it update the databse 2 or 3 times before the dislike partial appear . Is there any way I can use this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution for this question it was very easy I was trying to generate the routes not in rails way so I did some changes . First I added

```
resources :feed_likes
```

and then replace the links like this :

```
<%= link_to "Dislike", feed_like_path(:feed_id => @feed, :user_id => current_user.id ), :confirm => 'Are you sure?',:remote => true, :method => :delete,data: { disable_with: "Processsing..." }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>

 <%= link_to "like", feed_likes_path(:feed_id => @feed, :user_id => current_user.id ), :confirm => 'Are you sure?',:remote => true, :method => :post, data: { disable_with: "Processsing..." }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```